# Inserting a Blockquote into a Spoiler

Tags: bug, spoilers, blockquote

I would like the whole text to be a spoiler, but within this I need to have a blockquote

> This line should be part of a spoiler
> > This line should be a block quote
>  this line should just be part of a spoiler.

I included the syntax that I thought it should be although this clearly doesn't work...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug. I read somewhere else that formatting doesn't work inside an spoiler. Now where's that link. . .

Comment: I didn't know if it was a bug, but an error popped up saying I needed to add the bug tag

Comment: The spoiler markup is quite borked anyway. Afterall you can't even have a paragraph break inside a spoiler block, and I'd wager that to be even less bothersome than a blockquote.

Comment: @ChristianRau Inside a spoiler I just use <br><br> for a new paragraph

Comment: Italics and quote marks are your friend... but then again, I detest the use of spoiler markup, so *shrug*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTML markup within the spoiler.

> This line should be part of a spoiler
>
> > This line should be a block quote
>
> this line should just be part of a spoiler.

```
>! This line should be part of a spoiler
>! <blockquote>This line should be a block quote</blockquote>
>! this line should just be part of a spoiler.
```

The blockquote line isn't hidden by the spoiler, but the content is. The blockquote is shown separately by hovering that particular block of the spoiler ([bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260953/inconsistency-with-blockquote-in-spoiler-between-preview-and-post)).

Comment: Is there a way so that it doesn't have to be hovered over separately?

Comment: @qwertylpc [I've posted a bug report.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260953/inconsistency-with-blockquote-in-spoiler-between-preview-and-post)