# Inconsistency with blockquote in spoiler between preview and post

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, spoilers, blockquote

When [inserting a blockquote in a spoiler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260887/inserting-a-blockquote-into-a-spoiler), the preview indicates that hovering the parent blockquote (spoiler) will show the entire contents of the blockquote and any child blockquotes.

[image]

However, in the actual post, the blockquote within the spoiler requires hovering separately.

[image]

Could this discrepancy be fixed so that the preview matches the actual post? Personally I don't mind which one is 'correct' but it would appear that the [former has support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260887/inserting-a-blockquote-into-a-spoiler/260905?noredirect=1#comment850918_260905).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of build 3740 on MSE/MSO, and build 2863 on other sites.

Existing posts are not retroactively fixed; they will be fixed the next time you edit them.